# java SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, spring, rest, sockets, network-programming

I am getting the following exception while requesting data from a third party api. The issue happens rarely but still is a critical loss. Any suggestions as to how to prevent it will be helpful.

Here is the stack trace.

```
transaction-load: <11>147500407977748914 transaction-load com.mycompany.nmi.client.NmiApiRestTemplateImpl[]: getTransactions() failed: http request failed: Connection reset
com.mycompany.nmi.client.rest.RestException: http request failed: Connection reset

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:554)
    sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:509)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:944)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1353)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
    org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
    com.mycompany.nmi.client.rest.RestClientServiceSpringImpl.getRequest(RestClientServiceSpringImpl.java:96)    
    com.mycompany.nmi.client.rest.RestClientServiceSpringImpl.getRequest(RestClientServiceSpringImpl.java:156)
    com.mycompany.nmi.client.NmiApiRestTemplateImpl.getTransactionsList(NmiApiRestTemplateImpl.java:158)
    com.mycompany.nmi.client.request.GetTransactionsListRequest.execute(GetTransactionsListRequest.java:172)
    com.mycompany.transactionload.stl.reader.SystemTransactionLoadReader.loadTransactions(SystemTransactionLoadReader.java:528)
    com.mycompany.transactionload.stl.reader.SystemTransactionLoadReader.init(SystemTransactionLoadReader.java:263)
    com.mycompany.transactionload.stl.reader.SystemTransactionLoadReader.read(SystemTransactionLoadReader.java:468)
    com.mycompany.transactionload.stl.reader.SystemTransactionLoadReader.read(SystemTransactionLoadReader.java:61)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.read(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:155)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
    org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post full stack trace?

Comment: posted the full trace.

Comment: there are even framework to deal with this kind of occasional error: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry (batch.repeat sounds very similar though) - for longer term outages you may have to store the failed service call in a database of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

This will come when one side of the connection decides (or is forced to) to abruptly end the connection.  This can come from things that are entirely outside of your control, for example a server crashing.

You cannot prevent this 100% of the time, so you need to build logic to deal with it when it happens (for example, reconnect and resend).